# How to allow scrolling to view complete command output in the command-line?

Tags: command-line, execute-command, output

An example:

When I enter `compgen -c` to view all possible terminal commands I get something like this:

```
ll
ls
which
if
then
else
elif
fi
case
esac
for
select
while
until
do
done
```

and quite a bit more... but I can't see it all. When I scroll to the top of the output, I can't see the command I entered so it's obvious that the rest of the output is also not visible.

Comment: what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: assume the default when it is not told ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the scroll buffer larger. For the default terminal see edit  > profiles  > edit > scrolling and increase "limit scrollback". Example:

[image]

That will make it show more lines when you scroll up.

You can also use

```
compgen -c | more
compgen -c | less
compgen -c | most
```

(`most`  requires it to be installed `sudo apt-get install most`) to make it show 1 page at a time.

Or if you have a LOT of lines that even the buffer has trouble with put the result in a text file and view that one.

```
compgen -c > temp.txt
vi temp.txt
```

`vi` you can use things like :2 to go to page 2.